# Mold or dry sourdough starter? (pic included)

Tags: baking, sourdough

I fed my starter and left it out for two days.  See attached pic.  It smells like beer (which as I understand it is good), the top is dried out a bit with a rubbery surface, underneath it seems nice and active with no signs of mold.  I can't tell if the white spots are surface mold or if its just the dried out flour.  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like it's just dried out on top and a little overfermented. pour off as much liquid as you can and feed it using a small portion of this starter and a lot of flour and water, i would recommend a 1-10-10 ratio.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that a go.  Is it safe to assume if it were mold that it'd clearly smell as such?  Nothing about it smells "off" to me....

Comment: @Brad - Yeah, you'd have no doubt if it was mold.

Comment: For what its worth, I did what you suggested and it worked like a champ.  Baking with it today :)